# Echo inner join to $row

Tags: php

Hello I've this query to populate table from database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>#</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Grupo</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Grupo</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Ação</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['id_cliente'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['id_grupo'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['cliente'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id_cliente'] ."' title='Ver Registo' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='mdi mdi-magnify'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id_cliente'] ."' title='Actualizar Registo' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='mdi mdi-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id_cliente'] ."' title='Apagar Registo' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='mdi mdi-sync'></span></a>";
                                        echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";
                            // Free result set
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                            echo "<p class='lead'><em>Sem registos</em></p>";
                        }
                    } else{
                        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }

                    // Close connection
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
```

The values in the echo $row['id_grupo'] are numeric but related to another table.

I know the query to run inside the php myadmin in order to inner join values from two tables:

```
SELECT grupos.grupo 
    FROM clientes 
    INNER JOIN grupos 
    ON  clientes.id_grupo = grupos.id_grupo
```

How do I echo this on the $row['id_grupo'] ??

Comment: Change your SQL statement in your PHP to be you example one, but in the SELECT, you can probably use `SELECT clientes.*, groupos.grupo`, then access it in PHP with `$row['grupo']`.

Comment: What about use the stack overflow in Portuguese? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
SELECT clientes.*, grupos.grupo 
    FROM clientes 
    INNER JOIN grupos 
    ON  clientes.id_grupo = grupos.id_grupo
```

Instead `SELECT * FROM clientes`

And you have the value `$row['grupo']` in the `while`

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was using similar but making the wrong SELECT...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Alias** here for column name something like:

```
SELECT clientes.id_grupo as c_group, grupos.id_grupo as g_group
// rest of your query.
```

then you can get these columns in `$row` as:

```
$row['c_group'] // value from clientes table
$row['g_group'] // value from groups table
```

**Side Note:**
*MySQL ALIASES can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.*

[Useful link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)